# GCE: cannot login, The VM guest environment is outdated and only supports the deprecated 'sshKeys' metadata item

Tags: wordpress, ssh, ssh-keys, google-compute-engine

I cannot ssh into my Google Compute Engine (GCE) Wordpress instance anymore.
It was working one month ago when I tried last.
I use the Google built-in SSH client in a Chrome browser window.
Yesterday I tried an got the following message:

> The VM guest environment is outdated and only supports the deprecated
>   'sshKeys' metadata item. Please follow the steps here to update.

The "Steps here" link navigates to https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/configuring-imported-images#install_guest_environment which does not seem to help me much.

I am not aware of any changes that I may have made.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

It looks like your instance's disk is full, and so the SSH keys can't be created in the temp directory. You can do the following:

1. Stop your instance and wait for it to shut down
2. Click on the disk your instance is using, and choose "edit" at the top
3. Enter a larger disk size, and save
4. Go back to your instance and start it up again

You should now be able to connect via SSH. While you're in there, check to see what filled up your hard disk so you can prevent this from happening again (maybe a rogue program is printing out too many logs, etc).

Comment: I enlarged the disk but ssh still gives the same error. Maybe because I have to extend the partition in Linux. But I cannot login to the instance so I cannot extend it. What now?

Comment: I tried the same thing, adding 100GB and nothing changed.  Still get the same SSH keys error.  I also tried making a snapshot of the disk and creating a new instance with it.

Comment: I made a snapshot of the disk and mounted it on another vm. The disk is 10GB large, du -ks on mounted disk shows only 3.2GB in use so disk full does not seem to be the issue.

Comment: If you can't SSH into the instance then you can check the disk usage by reading the serial port output on https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instancesDetail/..<path_to_instance>../console. There should be a message that says something like ... "write error: No space left on device"

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing this on **Debian 8 or 9**, the most likely reason for this is that the `google-compute-engine.*` packages that allow SSH access to the instance have been removed by `apt-get autoremove`.

If you have an open SSH connection to the machine or can use a tool like `gcloud`, running `apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gce-compute-image-packages` should fix this.

If you no longer have any SSH access, there is [a procedure available on the GCP docs site](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/linux-guest-environment#startup_script) that can be used to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [bug report here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67997017) for this.

Comment: To summarize from the bug report: the cause of my problem was that apt autoremove had removed the Linux Guest Environment on this vm (debian). Google have updated their packages to add them to the NeverAutoRemove list at /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-gce.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but you can

1) Stop the VM

2) Edit and enable serial console

3) Use the serial connection to login and update the VM

Answer (score 0):

recent days, I meet similar problem, later I find the permission rights of my home directory fools me, as a lazy-bone, I chmod 777 ~
After did that, I cannot ssh via my terminal, even cannot ssh via browser, only get 'The VM guest environment is outdated and only supports the deprecated 'sshKeys' metadata item, Plese follow the steps here to update'. Sounds like you must set 755 to your home dir, not just care your 700 .ssh or 600 authorized_keys.

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar issue after I created a FreeBSD VM, gcloud ssh not works, but I am lucky that I can use the browser window ssh to my VM. Then I manually add the google_compute-engine public key to the .ssh/authorized_keys, now it work, I can use the gcloud ssh to connect. But not sure if this is a better/security way.