# Error: The VM guest environment is outdated and only supports the deprecated 'sshKeys' metadata item. Please follow the steps here to update

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Every time I stop a VM Instance from VM instance details page or do

```
sudo reboot
```

from inside the vm

When I try to connect to the vm using ssh I get this message

**The VM guest environment is outdated and only supports the deprecated 'sshKeys' metadata item. Please follow the steps here to update.**

How can I fix this error and connect to the vm?

Ps:

[the mentioned steps are at this page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/configuring-imported-images#install_guest_environment)

and I can't follow them because I can't connect to the vm

Comment: Have you followed the mentioned steps to update?

Comment: No. Because following the steps requires connecting to the vm which I can't do. See link above.

Comment: A user in the community has already requested help with a similar issue. Please go to this link [1] below where there is discussion about a possible solution:
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805429/gce-cannot-login-the-vm-guest-environment-is-outdated-and-only-supports-the-de

Answer (score 0):

On the page you linked to, with instructions, there are TWO primary ways to add the "Guest Environment" which should stop the error you're encountering. I encountered the same error by trying to use ssh by logging in as "root". You said that you tried the first method, but first you must gain access with a username that is loaded into the virtual machine via your metadata:

1. Have you tried using a different username to gain ssh access to the server? (Click on the gear on the top right of the browser based ssh terminal, and then select "Change Linux Username" and just put in a different name besides "root" -your google account name will usually work). If this works, then you CAN follow the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/linux-guest-environment#in_place).
2. If you have tried changing the username but get the same error, have you tried following the instructions that allow you basically pre-pend the scripts before the virtual machine starts? Those instructions are [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/linux-guest-environment#startup_script).